# SHA-256 Hashing problem from binary values

Tags: hash, sha-256

For a school project we have been given some example hexadecimal numbers to hash like the following:

```
Len = 2 (in bits)
Msg = c0
SHA 256 - MD = 1e1cea10a23697dc97b423c259842ac12ee679d6b43f088f3c32b26dbbfb0d79
```

The binary representation of `c0` is `11000000`, but as the length is 2 units, I assume that the binary number to be hashed is 11, which corresponds to 3 in decimal. Using online hash converters, I cannot get the example hash value back. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To clarify: why are you converting things to binary notation?

Comment: It is given in the description of the exercise.Recall that the binary representation of c0 is 11000000. Then
● The first sample message is 2 bits in length and is 11

Comment: 11000000 is 8 bits in length, not 2, a 0 bit is still a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hash exactly 2 bits set to 1. Two bits need to be padded, remembering that this is the last block. In that case the result is correct.

Note that representing two bits with hex value `C0` is not correct. `C0` represents a full byte and there is no reason to use the most significant bits rather than the lowest significant bits. Two bits set to one should simply be represented as `11` in binary.

---

I calculated the required result by performing a digest of the value `E0` (the value with an additional padding bit set to 1, and the rest 0 valued padding bits: `11 1 0 0000`), skipping the usual padding byte `80` (or 1000 0000 in binary), padding with zero valued bytes and then finally setting the (internal, encoded) length to 2. A bit messy, but it works.